# Cannot install npm package from CodeArtifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-codeartifact

I store my npm package in private repo inside CodeArtifacts. My package uses a bunch of external dependencies.

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
        "dayjs": "^1.11.3",
        "lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
        "maska": "^1.5.0",
        "nanoid": "^4.0.0",
        "pinia": "^2.0.14",
        "pug": "^3.0.2",
        "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.52.3",
        "sass-loader": "^13.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37"
    },
```

So, the problem is that I cannot install this package in my projects because I got this error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://repo-address.amazonaws.com/npm/repo/lodash.merge - Package, 'lodash.merge', not found.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'lodash.merge@^4.6.2' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Why npm trying to install these dependencies from my repo? I don't think I have to copy all the dependencies to my repo.